# Deploying Windows application in Nvidia Docker

Tags: docker, kubernetes, vagrant, vagrant-windows, nvidia-docker

I am planning to containerize legacy gpu intensive windows application using Nvidia Docker and kubernetis. But nvidia docker doesn't support windows as of now. please suggest some ideas. can I use RancherVM or kubevirt?

Comment: I guess you've looked at the comment on https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#is-microsoft-windows-supported ?

Comment: Vagrant? https://www.vagrantup.com/

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49589229/is-gpu-pass-through-possible-with-docker-for-windows

Comment: @Ryan yes I have seen the Nvidia documentation. I know that Nvidia docker won't support windows.  I would like to get around this. Can we use VM like ranchervm or kubevirt

Comment: So you're looking for non-docker alternatives and you want to deploy to kubernetes? Are you looking for orchestration of multiple virtual instances or is it enough to just virtualise and run one instance?

Comment: No I wanted to use docker. Preferably Nvidia docker. I am newbie in docker and kubernetes. So I am not surevhow to solve this use case. I am thinking of following solution.  1) I will have Nvidia docker and another docker in which I have VM with windows as guest OS. In guest windows I can run my windows application.  Which in turn need to access  Nvidia docker for you resource. Will this work?